# How can this canvas animation be made more efficient? It makes my fans spin up

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVVGLg

The main part; the animation function:

```
function animate() {
    t++
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    for (var i = 40; i < max; i+= 60) {
        var radius = Math.floor(i+Math.sin(t/10)*10)
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(center[0], center[1], radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.stroke()
    }

requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: **Minor help:** You could create one path instead of many circle paths (use moveTo). **Minor help:** Your code could be a bit tighter (array references, the radius values could be precalculated). **Your big hit is** that you are redrawing approx. 2/3 of the full screen each 1/60th second. That's **just a lot of drawing** and the only way to avoid it is to redraw fewer pixels per second.

Comment: i wonder if a fillRect using a radial gradient wouldn't be faster (might be a shader...). Store a few (30 ?) of those gradients and animate through them. (i've tried recently and it looked nice (for a pulsating glow effect). ( Rq : You need to build a few helper functions to avoid getting mad with the gradients :-))